# How to immediate greater and smaller value and select the value?

Tags: java

I have a scenario to take the maximum value from the nearest number and match with that number with .if it is match click action would  perform..all conditions I put it in a for loop..

```
public static int insertBeforeAfterMethod(int i, String event, String shotType, WindowsDriver < WebElement > mainEntrySession) {

    for(int cellIndex = 14;cellIndex < pbp_insert_grid_cells.size();cellIndex+=17)  //  
    {



        System.out.println(pbp_insert_grid_cells.size());
        rowSequenceNo = pbp_insert_grid_cells.get(cellIndex).getText();

        String[] splitvalue=rowSequenceNo.split("\\.");
        int guiSequenceNo=Integer.parseInt(splitvalue[0]);
        System.out.println("hello gui sequence number....."+guiSequenceNo);

            //i==4 here i==3
            if ((i%2!=0) && (sequenceNo < guiSequenceNo)) //1.5 <2  insert before
            { 
                System.out.println("hello"+i);
                next =guiSequenceNo; //2
                System.out.println("next"+next);
                break; 
            }
            else if((i%2==0) && (sequenceNo > guiSequenceNo)) //insert after
            {
                previous=guiSequenceNo;
                break;
            }





        if(next==guiSequenceNo) // 2==rowSequenceNo   insert before
        {
            System.out.println(cellIndex);
            WebElement sequenceCellNoInsertBefore = mainEntrySession.findElementByName(pbp_insert_grid_cells.get(cellIndex).getAttribute("Name"));

            rowNumber = sequenceCellNoInsertBefore.getAttribute("Name").substring(16);
            System.out.println(rowNumber);
            if(mainEntrySession.findElementByName(rowNumber).isDisplayed())
            {
                rowToClick = mainEntrySession.findElementByName("Period " +rowNumber);
                rowToClick.click();
                action.moveToElement(rowToClick).contextClick().perform();
                mainEntrySession.findElementByName("Insert Before").click();                    
                mainEntrySession.findElementByAccessibilityId("6").click();
                retValue = getNexti(i, event,shotType,mainEntrySession);
                System.out.println("return i "+retValue);


            }
        }
        else if(previous==guiSequenceNo)  //insert after
        {
            WebElement sequenceCellNoInsertAfter = mainEntrySession.findElementByName(pbp_insert_grid_cells.get(cellIndex).getAttribute("Name"));

        rowNumber = sequenceCellNoInsertAfter.getAttribute("Name").substring(16);
        System.out.println(rowNumber);
        if(mainEntrySession.findElementByName(rowNumber).isDisplayed())
        {
            rowToClick = mainEntrySession.findElementByName("Period " +rowNumber);
            rowToClick.click();
            action.moveToElement(rowToClick).contextClick().perform();
            mainEntrySession.findElementByName("Insert After").click();                 
            mainEntrySession.findElementByAccessibilityId("6").click();
            retValue = getNexti(i, event,shotType,mainEntrySession);
            System.out.println("return i "+retValue);


        }

    }

}

    return retValue;        
}
```

here the for looping is not incrementing it is exiting...without break how to take immediate greater and smaller and store it in a variable...?

Comment: So you have `sequenceNo` and `guiSequenceNo` and you want to do one thing if `sequenceNo > guiSequenceNo` and another different thing if `sequenceNo < guiSequenceNo`?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson. I want to find ,here I means current row value, if row value not even, then find the immediate greater value, if not find immediate smaller value and then take that value to match other condition.if it matches click that action...here I am using break statement, so my matching condition is not working. It is exit from for loop

Comment: I think your `for` loop is flawed as its index (`cellIndex`) is not used anywhere in the loop. Further, the variables in your `if` statements, ie. `i`, `sequenceNo` and `guiSequenceNo` are not changed within the loop. So your loop will do the same thing every time it executes. Perhaps this is to do nothing - without knowing the values of `i`, `sequenceNo` and `guiSequenceNo`, it's impossible for me to say. Your best bet is to use your debugger, ie. step through your `for` loop as it executes and see what's actually happening.

Comment: @dave currently i=3, sequenceNo=1.5, gui = 1, 2.... take the 2 that is stored i next

Comment: @Anthony if `i ==3`, then `i % 2 == 1`, so we're looking at the first `if` statement. If `sequenceNo == 1.5` and `guiSequenceNo == 1` in the first instance, then this condition will fail as `sequenceNo > guiSequenceNo`. There's nothing in the code you've shown that increases `guiSequenceNo`, so I would imagine this loop would run to completion without doing anything. Again, I would suggest using your debugger, it will show you what's actually happening.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to break the loop before execution rest of the statements .If first if else works only second if else condition will satisfy . You can remove the break from the first if else and put it in second if else .So that it will add before or after based on it and break it. Try and let me know @Anthony

Comment: If you think it will check for all the time . You can move the second if else outside the for loop and maintain with break and declare next and previous outside the loop @Anthony

Comment: @Abdul  i am taking immediate largest and smallest value.thas the reason am using break..without break how i get the immediate largest value and store it in next variable

Comment: Yes . You need a break but you need to break it after the second if else success only not on first if else success. because you got the immediate value and breaking it immediately without perform your actions . You need to break after success of second if else loop or move the second if else block outside the for loop @Anthony